# Как увеличить лимит запросов к Youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api

делал для практики аналог Youtube, понравилось что есть возможность получать действительно видео с ютуба и рендерить. Но там есть ограничения . И за час разрабтки я все исчерпал, возможно ли снять это ограничения( желательно бесплатно _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как описано в [документации](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota): "Если вы исчерпали свою квоту, вы можете запросить дополнительную квоту, заполнив ["Форму запроса дополнительной квоты"](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) для сервисов Youtube API.